# Javascript and automatic semicolon insertion

Tags: javascript, parsing

[test262](http://test262.ecmascript.org) test suite has [test](http://hg.ecmascript.org/tests/test262/file/927ea8563f7f/test/suite/ch07/7.9/S7.9_A5.7_T1.js) containing source:

```
var x=0, y=0;
var z=
x
++
++
y
```

The annotation says:

> Since LineTerminator(LT) between Postfix Increment/Decrement Operator(I/DO) and operand is not allowed, two IO(just as two DO and their combination) between two references separated by [LT] after automatic semicolon insertion lead to syntax error

Why does this code lead to syntax error? I think it's a valid code snippet. The code above equals to `var z=x; ++ ++ y;`. Expression `++ ++ y` is [allowed](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4) by javascript grammar. So what's the problem?

Comment: `++ ++ y` is **not allowed at all**!

Comment: @Neal but what about this production `UnaryExpression : ++UnaryExpression` ?

Comment: @sergeyz: Productions aren't everything. You could say it's sort of a runtime error, but it's detectable at compile time, since `++` can only take a reference as its operand, but can never yield one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will become:

```
var z = x;
++ ++ y;
```

The `++ ++ y` is the root of the problem. Let’s look at why...

`++ ++ y` gets evaluated as `++(++y)`. The first step is to evaluate `(++y)`. The `++` operator increments the value referenced by the variable it is next to, and returns the incremented value. The important part here is that it *does not return a reference, just a value*. So the second step would be `++(1)`, (or whatever `++y` yielded), which is an error, since only references can be incremented.

Comment: Just as I find the same explanation in ECMA-262, you post this answer :) It's hard to extract these rules from the standard, but it's basically [step 1 of `PutValue`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.2), which is invoked by [step 5 of the prefix increment operator](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.4).

Comment: @Tinctorius PutValue rules say `If Type(V) is not Reference, throw a ReferenceError exception.` So de jure expression `++ ++ y;` leads to runtime error (exception) ? Not parse error?

Comment: It's usually caught by static analysis. If the compiler is certain that the types are safe (e.g. only if `Type(V)` is a `Reference`, in this case) at compile-time, you can skip a lot of type checking at run-time. It's not a parse error, it could be a runtime error, but it's usually a compile-time error during analysis.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to implement js parser. I believe it's better to correct original grammar from specification and report syntax error: `UnaryExpression: ++LeftHandSideExpression`

Answer (score -1):

That evaluates to:

```
var x = 0, y = 0;
var z = x ++ ++ y; //MAKES NO SENSE!
```

Comment: No, it doesn't. Postfix increment may not be separated by a line terminator. It really is `var z = x; ++ ++ y;`.

Comment: @Tinctorius still illegal.

Comment: @Neal why `++ ++ y;` is illegal? Is it parsing error or runtime error?

Answer (score -1):

The grammar does not allow a new-line to precede a `++` or `--` operator; such a new-line must be converted to a `;`. Consequently, the expression must be parsed as though it had been:

```
var x = 0 , y = 0 ;
var z = x ;
++ ;
++ y ;
```

The third line is illegal.

References:

> Section 7.9.1, "Rules of Automatic Semicolon Insertion", rule 3
>
> Section 11.3, "11.3 Postfix Expressions".

Comment: That's not how it is interpreted. You're allowed to have line terminators between prefix increment/decrement and its operand.

Comment: Only *postfix* operators have the “no line break” rule. Prefix operators can consume as many line breaks as they want. Of course, why you would ever want to is beyond me :)

Comment: @rici [this production](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4) allows expressions `like ++ ++ y;`. It means your code equals to `var z = x; ++ ++ y;`, not `var z = x; ++; ++ y;`. So according to grammar parser accepts input and error actually is runtime exception?

Comment: @sergeyz: indeed, the UnaryExpression production allows multiple autoincrements, even though the PostfixExpression does not. (Truly odd, since in almost no case is a repeated prefix operator meaningful.) So, I agree, I was wrong, and so is the test case.

Comment: @sergeyz, i checked both mozilla js implementations (SpiderMonkey and JägerMonkey) and both of them implement UnaryExpression as though it included `++ LeftSideExpression | -- LeftSideExpression`, as is also shown in this old Mozilla grammar: http://www-archive.mozilla.org/js/language/grammar14.html . The Google V8 engine parses according to the actual standard, but checks if the argument of prefix ++/-- is a LeftSideExpression and, if not, converts it to a runtime exception; there's a comment which says this is for compatibility with JSC.